# get specific value key pair using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I only want to capture the values of "duration" and "start", so in the example below it would be 288 and 0 respectively.

How do I do this in the this loop?

```
    onPlaylist: function(event){
                           var arrayTime = jwplayer("container").getPlaylist();
                           var key;
                           for (key in arrayTime){
                               if (!arrayTime.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                                   continue;
                               }
                                   console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayTime[key])); 
                              }
```

Here are the console.log results:

{"provider":"video","file":"videos/Set1_mid.flv","image":"thumbs/set1_mid.jpg","description":"5 minute cardio with hand weights",
"author":"","duration":288,"title":"04:48","date":"","link":"","type":"video","start":0,
"mediaid":"","streamer":"","levels":[{"width":0,"bitrate":0,"url":"videos/Set1_mid.flv"}],"tags":"","index":0}

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new object with just the data you want.

```
var item = arrayTime[key];
console.log(JSON.stringify({ duration: item.duration, start: item.start }));
```

Comment: Thank you Quentin
    var item = arrayTime[key];
    var routineStart, routineDuration;
    routineStart = JSON.stringify(item.start);
    routineDuration = JSON.stringify(item.duration);